# Cant build correct Regular Expression for Mod Rewrite/URLRewriteFilter. How do I negate a range?

Tags: regex, tomcat, mod-rewrite, oracle-apex, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am having trouble building such a simple rule. I want to clean a URL only if the class 1 variable does not fall between 4000 and 5999.

When the user goes to `f?p=3999:1:1:::::` I want the user to be directed to `/3999/1?vars=:1:::::`.  If the user goes to `f?p=4000:1:1:::::` the URL will not be cleaned.

Here is what I have thus far.  This does what I want it to with the exception of the range.  Someone please help!:

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <note>
        FROM= URL typed in by user
        TO= URL user is redirected to.
    </note>
    <from>^/f\?p=([0-9A-Za-z]+):([0-9A-Za-z]+):([0-9A-Za-z]*)(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/$1/$2?vars=$3$4</to>
</rule>
```

Using the solution provided by Lindrian, I was able to insert it into my code to get desired results.

The final solution:

```
<rule match-type="regex">
<note>
    FROM= URL typed in by user
    TO= URL user is redirected to.
</note>
<from>^/f\?p=((?:[0-3]|[6-9])[0-9]*|[54]\d{4,}):([0-9A-Za-z]+):([0-9A-Za-z]*)(.*)$</from>
<to type="redirect">/$1/$2?vars=$3$4</to>
```

What I am doing here is using URLRewriteFilter to clean up an oracle application express URL. The issue here is that APEX is using relative referencing so if you login to APEX the linked pages will now look for $1/f?p...  as the linked paged.  This errors out because $1 doesnt exist!  So, I turned URL cleaning off for the development UI

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the mod-rewrite code, but I can help you with your regular expression. Even though regex is not the best tool for doing things like this, it can be done.

I have created a short simple regular expression that matches all digits but those in the range of `4000`to `5999`: http://regex101.com/r/aU5qC4

I hope you can make this work with your other code.

Good luck.